Why is the second order correction to energy zero for a fully degenerate eigensystem?
Consider the system given by,
$$ H|n\rangle = E|n\rangle$$
where:

$H$ is the hamiltonian.
$|n\rangle$ is the eigenstate.
$E$ is the energy of the eigenstate.

Using degenerate perturbation theory and referring to the reference here, equation (1.2.37), we see;
$$E_{n,k}^{(2)} = -\sum_{p}\frac{|\delta H_{p,nk}|^{2}}{E_{p}^{0} - E_{n}^{0}}\tag{1.2.37}$$
where:

$E_{n,k}^{(2)}$ denotes the $2^{nd}$ correction to the energy of the $k^{th}$ state among the $n$ degenerate states.
$E_{n}$ denotes the ground state energy of the $n^{th}$ state.
$(n,k)$ denotes the $k^{th}$ state among the $n$ degenerate states.
$p\in$ non-degenerate states.

We see that the summation is only occuring over the non-degenerate state space and it has no component contribution from the degenerate state space (for example there is no term that calculates the contribution of the $(n,l)^{th}$ state to the $(n,k)^{th}$ state.)
Does this mean that if my system is fully degenerate (non-degenerate state space is a null space, the second order correction to the energy is zero? (I do not understand why that would be.)

This site is for research level mathematics. Your question is about undergraduate level physics. Maybe try physics stack exchange.

Hello Dr. @JeffHarvey, I initially asked a similar question on physics stack exchange, however; that community is not very responsive. I thought the quickest way to get a correct answer would be to post here. Thank you.

If $H$ is fully degenerate, all eigenvalues are identical, it means that $H$ is proportional to the unit matrix. The zeroth order eigenstates can be chosen as any orthonormal basis. Degenerate perturbation theory requires that you choose this basis such that it diagonalizes the perturbation $\delta H$. In that basis the eigenvalues are just the diagonal elements of $\delta H$, the second order, and higher order, correction is zero.
Basically what happens is that if $H$ is fully degenerate it commutes with any $\delta H$, so the eigenvalues of $H+\delta H$ are simply given by the eigenvalues of $\delta H$, with a fixed offset from the eigenvalue of $H$.

Hello Dr. @CarloBeenakker, Thank you. I think I understand.
